# Handling 500 JRun servlet in ColdFusion

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8, jrun

All -

Is there a way to handle a 500 JRun servlet error in ColdFusion? I tried using `cferror` as well as using the site-wide handler in ColdFusion admin, but it does not seem to be working.

Here is the error message

```
500

ROOT CAUSE:  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException     at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseName(FormScope.java:408)   at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseQueryString(FormScope.java:360)    at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parsePostData(FormScope.java:328)   at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.fillForm(FormScope.java:278)    at
coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.SymTab_initForRequest(FusionContext.java:438)   at 
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:33)   at
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)  at 
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)  at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)  at
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)  at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)  at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)  at
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)  at
jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)     at
jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)  at
jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)   at
jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)   at
jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)    at
jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)   at 
jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)


javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException  at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseName(FormScope.java:408)   at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseQueryString(FormScope.java:360)    at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parsePostData(FormScope.java:328)   at
coldfusion.filter.FormScope.fillForm(FormScope.java:278)    at
coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.SymTab_initForRequest(FusionContext.java:438)   at 
coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:33)   at
coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22) at
coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:126)  at 
coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:200)  at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:89) at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:86)  at
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:42)  at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)  at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)  at
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)  at
jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)     at
jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)  at
jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)   at
jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)   at
jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)    at
jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)   at 
jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)  at
coldfusion.monitor.event.MonitoringServletFilter.doFilter(MonitoringServletFilter.java:70)  at
coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapFilter.doFilter(BootstrapFilter.java:46)  at 
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.doFilter(FilterChain.java:94)  at
jrun.servlet.FilterChain.service(FilterChain.java:101)  at
jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:106)     at
jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)  at
jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:286)   at
jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)   at
jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)    at
jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)   at 
jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)
```

Comment: If it is a JRun error than it is likely occurring before any ColdFusion handlers can trap it.  Can you post the actual error message please?

Comment: Miguel-F - I have edited my question with the error message.

Comment: Do you know what is causing this error and only want to know if there is a way to catch it?  Or are you trying to find out what is causing this error?

Comment: This is happening when I am using a firefox extension and change a hidden variable value for testing security vulnerabilities. The security vulnerability identified in this case is the error message 'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException'

Comment: What is the security vulnerability with that, information disclosure?

Comment: yes, information leakage.

Comment: Read over this page and see if that works for you, [JRun 4 Programmers Guide - Servlet Programming Techniques - Handling exceptions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/Programmers_Guide/techniques_servlet12.htm). I have not done this myself but perhaps others will chime in.

Comment: I am curious as to what you are passing in the form field that is causing this error.  Can you share?

Comment: %u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215%u002e%u002e%u2215etc%u2215hosts.

Comment: Another question, do you have `Enable Global Script Protection` turned on in the ColdFusion Administrator?  [ColdFusion Administrator - Settings Page](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=appSecurity_02.html).  Not sure if it will catch this or not.

Comment: Yes, it is enables, but does not make any difference

Comment: (Edit fix typos) @Miguel-F is correct. The error occurs before CF ever makes it to the Application file, so `cferror` will not catch it. Specify an error page in your web.xml file and restart. That should do it. ie `<error-page><error-code>500</error-code><location>/someErrorPage.htm</location>‌​</error-page>`. See his link for more details.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation @Leigh. I have added an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error that you are receiving is occurring at the JRun level.  This type of error occurs before the ColdFusion error handler can trap it.  You will need to create and assign an error handler at the JRun level.  This can be accomplished by editing the web.xml file. (After making changes you will need to restart the JRun server.)

Details can be found on this page, [JRun 4 Programmers Guide - Servlet Programming Techniques - Handling exceptions](http://livedocs.adobe.com/jrun/4/Programmers_Guide/techniques_servlet12.htm).

> You can define how a web application handles errors using the `error-page` element in the WEB-INF/web.xml file. You can also define error handling for all web applications on the JRun server by adding `error-page` elements to the SERVER-INF/default-web.xml file.
>
> **Handling HTTP error codes**
>
> The `error-code` subelement of `error-page` in the web.xml file defines how JRun handles HTTP error codes generated during the processing of a servlet.
>
> You define an HTTP status code for the `error-code` element and then map the code to a destination in the `location` element. The following example maps the HTTP 500 (Internal Server Error) status code to the servererror.jsp page:
>
> ```
> <error-page>
>     <error-code>500</error-code>
>     <location>/error-pages/servererror.jsp</location>
> </error-page>
> ```
>
> The following table lists common error-related HTTP status codes:
>
> ```
> HTTP error code    Description
>   400              Bad Request
>   401              Unauthorized
>   403              Forbidden
>   404              Not Found
>   408              Request Time-out
>   500              Internal Server Error
> ```
>
> **Accessing error attributes**
>
> The `HttpServletRequest` and `HttpServletResponse` objects provide access to error information so that you can generate meaningful debugging information or targeted exception handlers. For more information and examples, see the link that I included above.
>
> JRun sets several attributes on the request object when an error is thrown. The following describes these attributes:
>
> - `javax.servlet.error.status_code` - Defines the HTTP error code, if applicable, as an int object. If the servlet throws an exception not related to HTTP, the status code is usually set to 500 (Internal Server Error).
> - `javax.servlet.error.message` - Returns the exception or error message.
> - `javax.servlet.error.exception_type` - Defines the type of exception.
> - `javax.servlet.error.exception` - Defines the actual exception thrown. You can use the printStackTrace method to view the stack trace of the exception.
> - `javax.servlet.error.request_uri` - Defines the request URI prior to the exception being thrown.

Comment: Thanks Miguel. I replicated the error on my local instance and got the custom error page working by updating the default-web.xml file. I am not sure how we would be handling this on prod version (As I do not have access to these files).But I atleast know what is happening.

Comment: Ask the server administrator to add a custom jrun error page the same way.

Comment: Does anyone know about the 503 error Jrun Servlet Error ?