# Using actionscript Xml.send() to coldfusion 7 stopped working after flash player update

Tags: coldfusion, actionscript, flash

I have a web site that is build using Flash 8 and actionscript 2.0. This connects to a coldfusion 7 server to print content for the user like reports etc. This has been working for many years now but since an update to Flash Player, since the 15+ release, this printing has stopped working and now I get the following error

> 500
>
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException    at
>   coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseQueryString(FormScope.java:283)  at
>   coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parsePostData(FormScope.java:255)     at
>   coldfusion.filter.FormScope.fillForm(FormScope.java:206)  at
>   coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.SymTab_initForRequest(FusionContext.java:384)
>     at coldfusion.filter.GlobalsFilter.invoke(GlobalsFilter.java:33)    at
>   coldfusion.filter.DatasourceFilter.invoke(DatasourceFilter.java:22)
>     at
>   coldfusion.filter.RequestThrottleFilter.invoke(RequestThrottleFilter.java:115)
>     at coldfusion.CfmServlet.service(CfmServlet.java:107)   at
>   coldfusion.bootstrap.BootstrapServlet.service(BootstrapServlet.java:78)
>     at jrun.servlet.ServletInvoker.invoke(ServletInvoker.java:91)   at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunInvokerChain.invokeNext(JRunInvokerChain.java:42)    at
>   jrun.servlet.JRunRequestDispatcher.invoke(JRunRequestDispatcher.java:259)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.ServletEngineService.dispatch(ServletEngineService.java:543)
>     at
>   jrun.servlet.jrpp.JRunProxyService.invokeRunnable(JRunProxyService.java:203)
>     at
>   jrunx.scheduler.ThreadPool$ThreadThrottle.invokeRunnable(ThreadPool.java:428)
>     at jrunx.scheduler.WorkerThread.run(WorkerThread.java:66)

I have tried the solution from
[Handling 500 JRun servlet in ColdFusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15507460/handling-500-jrun-servlet-in-coldfusion). This stopped the error showing on screen but instead i just get nothing displaying

The following code is the way in which I call the coldfusion page

```
    var xmlString:String = "<rootNode>";
    // More xml
    xmlString += "</rootNode>";
    var xmlObj = new XML(xmlString);
    xmlObj.contentType = "text/xml";
    xmlObj.send( "https://domainname.com/printme.cfm", "_blank");
```

From testing I noticed that if I make xmlString an empty string then the above error stops but as soon as it is any text the error above reappears

Does any one have any ideas,
thanks

EDIT
As requested here are the headers from ServiceCapture

The first is from FireFox using flash player 15.0.0.233 and gives the 500 error.
the second is from IE using flash player 10.2.153.1 and prints correctly.
Both are accessing the same web site

One thing I noticed from ServiceCapture is that when it works the xml text is listed in a "Text" tab on the request side. When it does not work the xml is shown in a "Parameters" tab

```
POST /printme.cfm HTTP/1.1
Host: domainname.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 5.1; rv:33.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/33.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Cookie: CFID=8989; CFTOKEN=556456456456; JSESSIONID=4544545f93bea93a591513
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 2100



POST /printme.cfm HTTP/1.1
Accept: */*
Content-Type: text/xml
Accept-Language: en-gb
UA-CPU: x86
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.648; .NET CLR 3.5.21022; OfficeLiveConnector.1.3; OfficeLivePatch.0.0; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729)
Host: domainname.com
Content-Length: 2100
Cookie: CFID=23232; CFTOKEN=656565656; JSESSIONID=583078632234aa20506970
```

EDIT 2;
I noticed that in the first POST block the content-Type is set to "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
which is the default. For some reason the newer versions of flash player seam to be ignoring the line

```
xmlObj.contentType = "text/xml";
```

Additionally if I remove this line then I get the 500 error for both versions of player

Comment: you will need to post the CF code. A 500 error is generic and is obscuring the actual error. Try looking for it in the application.log.

Comment: thank you for your response, i didnt initally post the CF code as the tread I mention above says that this error is been cause by the jrun and is before the CF is even called. Even a simply <cfoutput>hello world</cfoutput> results in the same thing

Comment: Hmmm... ok, how about this. First, post the RAW http data - the XML packet and the http post headers - using firebug or wireshark. Then, on the CF side take a look in the /runtime/logs for the standard Java out log - sometimes titled "cfusion-out.log". That log has information not found in the CF logs. Perhaps a clue will emerge.

Comment: cfusion-out.log also had this 'warning Error while parsing POST data
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.parseQueryString(HttpUtils.java:149)
 at javax.servlet.http.HttpUtils.parsePostData(HttpUtils.java:252)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunRequest.parsePostData(JRunRequest.java:381)
 at jrun.servlet.JRunRequest.getParameters(JRunRequest.java:361)
'...

Comment: That's a very good clue! let's see what the RAW xml is that you are posting.

Comment: thanks again, any xml content ( in fact any content ) causes the error, so "<node><subNode>1</subNode></node>" causes it. Maybe missing headers or change chars to ascii ( &gt; for > etc )?

Comment: headers are a good possibility - something changed with your update to Flash. My first guess would actually be that Flash has restricted versions of SSL (for Poodle) but that doesn't mesh with the error - or the fact that you can send an empty string without error. Yet something is different and the error mentioned is that the post data can't be accessed or parsed.

Comment: Can you locate an OLD version of flash, capture the output from it, and compare with the NEW version?

Comment: i can try, capture using wireshark?

Comment: Thanks mark for your help, i figured it out in the end, was due to the content type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that the contentType "text/xml" was deprecated and the newer version of flash player must be more strict about setting it to valid value and updating my value to the default.
As soon as I changed it to "text/plain" all started working

Comment: Jock, that is awesome. I'm glad it was an easy fix eh?

Comment: thanks for your help, like most things yes it was an easy fix...when you know how to fix it :D. It was a worry as the only way our users could use the system was to install an old version of FP and then turn off auto updates, not the best solution